# How to filter an array by using conditions and get the array with preferred data in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Below is an array of objects I have,
I want the result as array of only the ids that are not equal to the string 'search'.

I tried the below syntax but its returning me the object but not the string.

result I

```js
const projects = [
 {projectId: "1111111", projectName: "A"},
 {projectId: "search", projectName: "B"},
 {projectId: "2222222", projectName: "C"},
 {projectId: "search", projectName: "D"},
 {projectId: "333333333", projectName: "E"}
 ];


const result = projects.filter((data) => data.projectId !== 'search' && data.projectId)

console.log(result)
```

need:

```
[
 "1111111"
 "2222222"
"333333333"
]
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop or `.reduce()` or add a `.map()` call, ...

Comment: @Andreas used .map() it worked, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). To dump the console log of the array is making it harder for us to test your code

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using `forEach`.

```
let newArray = []
const projects = [
   {projectId: "1111111", projectName: "A"},
   {projectId: "search", projectName: "B"},
   {projectId: "2222222", projectName: "C"},
   {projectId: "search", projectName: "D"},
   {projectId: "333333333", projectName: "E"}
];
projects.forEach(item =>{
    if(item.projectId !== 'search'){ 
        newArray.push(item.projectId)
    }
})
console.log(newArray) //["1111111", "2222222", "333333333"]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use filter() and map(),

```js
const projects = [
 {projectId: "1111111", projectName: "A"},
 {projectId: "search", projectName: "B"},
 {projectId: "2222222", projectName: "C"},
 {projectId: "search", projectName: "D"},
 {projectId: "333333333", projectName: "E"}
];
let result = projects
  .filter(({projectId}) => projectId !== 'search')
  .map(({projectId})=> projectId);

console.log(result);
```